# im4java Convert Crashes on Piped Input/Output

Tags: java, imagemagick

I'm using im4java to convert image. The following program crashes with stack trace: `Caused by: org.im4java.core.CommandException: convert: insufficient image data in file /tmp/magick-254901G7YJ9qaMQv5' @ error/jpeg.c/ReadJPEGImage/1154.`

Looks like it's generating a temp file. Running the same command directly on ImageMagick command lines gives me correct results.

I'm running `ImageMagick-6.9.10-61` and `im4java 1.4.0`

I wonder if anyone has any insights.

```
IMOperation op = new IMOperation();
op.addImage("-");
op.addImage("jpg:-");
op.quality(0.85);

try (ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
    // image is of type MultipartFile
    Pipe pipeIn = new Pipe(image.getInputStream(), null);
    Pipe pipeOut = new Pipe(null, outputStream);

    convertCmd.setInputProvider(pipeIn);
    convertCmd.setOutputConsumer(pipeOut);
    convertCmd.run(op);

    return outputStream.toByteArray();
} catch (Exception e) {
           //
}
```

Comment: Did you try creating a temp file yourself? Just to check whether it's the pipes or something else.

Comment: @Thomas How should I do that? The temp file created every time is different. Can I configure a file to use?

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at some older code where we've done something similar and I realized your problem is the use of 2 pipes where one has a null target and the other has a null source. That might cause the temp file to be used.

Instead of doing that you need to use *one single* pipe:

```
try (ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
  Pipe pipe = new Pipe(image.getInputStream(), outputStream);

  convertCmd.setInputProvider( pipe );
  convertCmd.setOutputConsumer( pipe );

  return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

From the [JavaDoc](https://github.com/Widen/im4java/blob/master/src/org/im4java/process/Pipe.java):

> You can use the same Pipe-object for both ends of a process-pipeline.

Comment: No luck. Still got the same error. Actually the code was from http://im4java.sourceforge.net/docs/dev-guide.html, under the pipe section. So I think the code is correct. Maybe configuration issues?

Comment: @JFreebird that could be the case. Did you make sure that you're using the same IM installation, image and parameters as on the command line?

Comment: yes, exactly the same.  I realized that I called the `Info()` before running convert, if I don't call `Info()` and use filesystem files as input/output (instead of pipe), then the issue is gone.